# How do I create a fixed navbar in an ASP.NET webapp?

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have tried create a fixed navbar in ASP.NET with the .NET 4.8 dev pack. Can somebody explain what is going on? I have tried:

```
<style>
   .navbar {
       position: fixed;

   }
</style>


<style>
   .navbar {
       position: sticky;
   }
</style>
```

and

```
<style>
   .navbar {
       position: static;
   }
</style>
```